# Can I use tagit with twitter bootstrap?

Tags: jquery, tags, twitter-bootstrap

I'm trying to integerate [tagit](http://aehlke.github.com/tag-it/) with twitter bootstrap's [typeahead](http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/javascript.html#typeahead) functionality.

I know that tagit relies on the jquery UI for autocomplete etc.  Is it possible to use twitters bootstrap instead?

Basically all I want from tagit is to let the user quickly click and remove items from a list but would prefer not to introduce another java script library on my site

Comment: There is also a multiple typeahead version here: https://github.com/twitter/bootstrap/pull/2007. But it's still textual.

Comment: that gets me closer.  Now if I can add the styling of tagit that would be perfect :)

Comment: Yeah, i'm interested too. I'll check this question for further updates. Also note that modded plugin allows duplicate entries.

Comment: Love your question. I've been struggling for a long time to make typeahead+tagsinput work together in Bootstrap 3 without success. I knew about the existence of TagIt but I didn't want to use jQueryUI together with Bootstrap. I'll try the posted answer below.

Answer (score 4):

Tagit is nice and I haven't found a suitable replacement. The good news is, [you don't need *all* of Jquery-UI](https://github.com/aehlke/tag-it/issues/61) and you can style the tag input yourself to look alright with Bootstrap.

SCSS:

```
ul.tagit {
  margin-left: 0;
  input { @include box-shadow(none); }
}
```

CSS:

```
ul.tagit {
  margin-left: 0;
}
ul.tagit input { 
     -webkit-box-shadow: none;
     -moz-box-shadow: none;
     box-shadow: none;
}
```

Comment: Hi, could you render that little SCSS snippet into normal CSS? That would help out lazy windows users like me...

Answer (score 1):

Made a small [example](http://jsfiddle.net/tySCe/9/), that is working, although ugly a bit. I'm not actually much good in CSS styling, so, hopefully, you'll make improvements to this example to make it completely fine.

Answer (score 1):

If you don't mind the jQuery UI dependency, you can use http://addyosmani.github.com/jquery-ui-bootstrap/ for styling jQuery UI to look like the default Bootstrap theme. It should play nicely with Tag-it -- please let me know if it doesn't as I haven't used it myself yet (I'm the author of Tag-it).

Comment: Hey, can I extend tag-it to use bootstrap typeahead? Any ideas on how to do so would be great help.

Comment: @gauravvgat I'd like much better bootstrap support. I have a version of the CSS in progress that'll remove the jQuery UI CSS dependency and allow tagit to be styled by bootstrap's CSS. I guess next step will be to allow swapping out jQuery UI autocomplete for typeahead... no ideas yet on how I will do this, not looking forward to it tbh :) Since I want to keep the API simple.

Comment: I just tried it with bootstrap 3.0, broke it :-) I guess you meant, to replace bootstrap?
May I suggest, just add a css version that works under bootstrap? Will do this eventually myself, probably